# No boot options after installing kubuntu

Tags: 20.04, usb-installation

On a windows laptop I installed Kubuntu LTS in Legacy Mode and told it to completely wipe my drive and isntall Kubuntu on the whole thing. It seemed to finish, but after restarting, I have no boot options in my BIOS.

I cannot install in UEFI mode as the screen goes black after grub, even with "no splash nomodeset" to deal with the nvidia GPU in the laptop. I cannot run boot-repair since it only works in UEFI mode. I attached the disk-repair pastebin, any help would be much appreciated.

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/5h3wQZr53q/
Additional Info:
Model: ASUS-k501ux
CPU: i5-6500u
GPU: Intel iGPU and nvidia 950m
SSD: Micron 256gb
USB: 8gb usb 2.0

Comment: If you're going to install in Legacy Mode, you need to make sure that you don't use UEFI in BIOS.  BIOS should also be set to Legacy Mode and the hard drive should be set in the Boot Options.  Preferably set to the first boot item.  Might want to see:  https://superuser.com/questions/1102836/cant-find-option-to-activate-legacy-boot-mode-on-asus-efi-bios

Comment: Better to install in UEFI mode with Secure Boot OFF. That's the problem due to the need of Nvidia drivers.